# How to restrict user from assigning task to one specific profile users

Tags: profile, user

I want to restrict users from assigning tasks to a group of user belong to one profile.How can I do that?

Comment: I have no idea how to restrict the user.can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for example with a validation rule (read about them in your help&training). We try to push into asking a good question that shows some research effort and discourage "plz send me teh codez / do the homework for me").

---

A validation rule on Task object with error formula similar to

```
Owner:User.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
```

should do the trick?

Notes:

1. In the formula editor you'll have to look for the field label ("Assigned To", not "Owner")
2. Up till Summer'13 release we had hard time doing that because Calendar could be also the task "owner"

Answer (score 1):

Just to jump in on this. I've currently got a validation rule running on "Assigned to Field"

```
$UserRole.Name !=  Owner:User.UserRole.Name
```

This ensures people can only make a task for users within their role.

---

However I want to also edit this so that users can make a task for a role within their role hierarchy, i.e. if their role reports to another role or if it is on top of another role then they can also make tasks for each other.

Such as within the example hierarchy below all users can make a role for each other. However I want to do this without specifying which role, as there are a large number of roles and role hierarchies in our salesforce system

- Case Admin Role
- Case Team Role
- Volunteer Role

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is super neat! i reckon everything under the line would make a great [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Agree with bigassforce here, answers really aren't a good place to ask question. If you're new to the site and unsure how we differ from forums, have a look at the [welcome tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour)